# React Native: How to use react-native-webgl-camera?

Tags: react-native

On the github `README` page of `react-native-webgl` [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-webgl) there is a mention of `react-native-webgl-camera` without any samples.

Anyone knows how to use it? Any working example with `Three.js` as a texture?

Comment: I have been trying to work out the exact same thing, i'm trying to get it to work with Viro React so i can get a THREEjs object rendered in augmented reality, which would be quite cool. Sadly, couldn't get anything working through the documentation or trying to install the examples

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?